# Faulty HDD? Lower performance 5400 RPM Asus Laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, performance

I've been using a pavillion G6 2301su for about 3 years and recently bought a new Asus k555l laptop in hopes to increase performance, in gaming and in work environments. Both laptops use HDD at 5400 RPM with only storage size and manufacturer being different.  At first it was good, The Asus booted up faster and was looking like a sound investment. But as the months went on , performance started to plummet, to a point where I had to format the whole hard-drive in order to be able to use the laptop normally, before that it was a complete nightmare to get stuff to run , write some files to the drive or browse or anything else for that matter.

Ok clean format did it, when I save text files to the hard drive before it took like 10 seconds, now it takes 2 which is the normal benchmark I had from Atom.io as I bought the configuration. It is still 2 seconds now, that hasn't slowed down, but the boot times are prehistoric, we are talking about 2-3 minutes to the Welcome logo of wndows 10 pro , and about 1-2 minutes till we get everything loaded up on the desktop. Everything == ESET NOD32 AV , Graphics and Touchpad drivers... which is bullcrap. My older laptop (the pavilion g6) loads faster than that, and it has to load skype and viber at the same time... this seems very unreasonable.

I would like to point out that the Asus is not nearly an year old , and its about 25% - 30% more expensive than the price of the HP at the time of buying.

Another note : I do hear some weird "scratching" from the laptop around where the right hand palm should be, and I'm guessing that's where my Hard drive is (that is where it was on the HP).
Not sure that's normal and I'm seriously considering springing for the warranty of this thing.

Why I think it's the HDD fault - Becoming a performance freak, I got a second monitor just to run the "performance monitor" and the "task manager" windows apps and watch what is causing this drop in performance. In 90% of the times the HDD was either completely fried at 99% usage with only 1 MB - 10 MB actual throughput, as the main source of traffic was the PageFile. And God forbid Windows decides to download updates in the background , its like im back on my 2002 pre-build PC from the shop nearby .... 99% Disk Uptime with speeds below 2MB / s !

Any ideas as to what might cause such significant drop in performance , and should I really spring for the warranty? (I work as a Web Developer for a small company, so being without my laptop for 2-4 weeks is kind of an issue, unless I am sure that the HDD is faulty and will be replaced by the manufacturer)

Comment: Probably not faulty, I have a laptop that does almost exactly the same. Some laptop drives are just painfully slow, especially with the small reads with heavy seeking that goes on at computer startup. An SSD would probably improve things.

Comment: guess it would but in our region it costs half your laptop to get a decent SSD with enough storage . Still can't figure out where and what that noise is... its not heavy scratching like nails on the harddrive but its almost like its clearing a layer of sand from the surface if that makes any sense

Comment: How much RAM does your laptop have?

Comment: 6 Gigs of RAM brother